# How can I add an alternative route to a controller method in MVC Core to support a legacy endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

The following code I am trying is changing the route so that it is *only* accessible via [Area]/[Controller]/DailyStatusSummary - is there any way to just add it as an alternative route?

```
    [HttpGet("[Area]/[Controller]/DailyStatusSummary")]

    public async Task<IActionResult> CompanyStatusSummary()
    { 
        ... etc.
```

Background:
I used to have a controller action named DailyStatusSummary. I have refactored my code to give better names to actions, and this means this action in particular is now called CompanyStatusSummary. I am wary some users have bookmarks to the old DailyStatusSummary endpoint as it's a popular page, so I am trying to add this as an alternative route (so if you navigate to either the old or new endpoint, it hits the CompanyStatusSummary action.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App_Start\RouteConfig.cs you can create a specific route. Assuming your area is "areaABC" and your controller is "controllerXYZ", and only the action changes, something like this may work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Alternate",
    url: "areaABC/controllerXYZ/DailyStatusSummary",
    defaults: new { area = "areaABC", controller = "controllerXYZ", action = "CompanyStatusSummary"}
);
```

And the action in the controller should keep the CompanyStatusSummary (or remove if catched with generic route):

```
[HttpGet("[Area]/[Controller]/CompanyStatusSummary")]

public async Task<IActionResult> CompanyStatusSummary()
{
```

For .Net Core 3.1, the route mapping should be done in app.UseEndpoints, mapping the controller route:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Alternate",
    pattern: "areaABC/controllerXYZ/DailyStatusSummary",
    defaults: new { area = "areaABC", controller = "controllerXYZ", action = "CompanyStatusSummary" });
```

Comment: Important: the custom route must be created BEFORE the generic MVC route. Routes are evaluated in order, and if one route matches the request URL the rest of the routes are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using core 3.1 and my existing routing code looks like this, can you provide a translation for the routes.MapRoute code that would fit into this? `            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });`